# Screen recording not working on iPadOS 13?

Tags: ipad, screen-sharing, ipados

I’ve been trying to get screen recording to work on my iPad Pro 9.7  for a while, but it seems to be greyed out. I know it isn’t restricted, as I have checked multiple times, and AirPlay mirroring still works. Is there anything which may be causing this to occur?

Answer (score 1):

Check how much free storage space do you have available on your iPad. If your iPad is low on storage space, screen recording and video capture via the camera app is disabled by iOS.

You can check for the amount of free storage space available on your device by going to Settings app → General → iPad Storage.

You can re-enable screen recording by freeing up space on your iPad which could be done via the iPad Storage section.

Comment: I checked, and I haven’t used over half of my device’s storage, so unfortunately I do not believe this is the case.

Comment: @Otherpianoguy I'd recommend restarting the iPad, updating the iPadOS to the latest version, and resetting it in that order, one by one.

Comment: I have done that multiple times, and it is running iPadOS 13.6.1, so I don’t believe that is this issue either.